# Стоит ли использовать наследование при небольшом изменении реализации?

Tags: java, ооп

Написал односвязный список на Java. В нем сделал методы

```
insertFirst(T item)
insertLast(T item)
insert(int position, T item)
removeFirst()
removeLast()
remove(int position)
get(int position)
isEmpty()
```

В моей реализации односвязного списка есть указатель на первый элемент списка. Этот класс называется `LinkedListWithHead`. Далее, я хочу написать еще одну реализацию односвязного списка, но используя уже указатель на первый и на последний элемент списка. Этот класс будет называться `LinkedListWithHeadAndTail`. Изменится реализация методов

```
insertFirst
insertLast
removeFirst
removeLast`
```

То есть, по сути, большую часть методов я вообще трогать не буду, поэтому не хочется заводить совсем новый класс и там все эти методы дублировать.

Но и наследование как то не очень тут вяжется, потому что `LinkedListWithHeadAndTail` не является разновидностью `LinkedListWithHead`. И вообще, пользователям моих классов может быть важно написать метод, принимающей исключительно объекты класса `LinkedListWithHead`, потому что они экономичнее по памяти. А если я завяжусь на наследовании, то в такой метод можно будет передать и объект класса `LinkedListWithHeadAndTail`. Может быть композиция будет выходом для меня? Если вложить объект класса `LinkedlistWithHead` в `LinkedListWithHeadAndTail`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Наследование нужно использовать если между новым и старым типами есть отношение *Is-A*: новый тип есть *разновидность* старого, и везде, где использовался объект старого типа, можно использовать и объект нового.

Использование наследования лишь для того, чтобы скопировать большую часть реализации — злоупотребление наследованием. Так делают довольно часто (особенно если язык не предоставляет удобных возможностей повторного использования реализации без наследования), но это неправильно, и может потенциально привести к проблемам.

---

Для вашего случая мне кажутся возможными два пути.

1. Вы заводите внутренний класс со статическими функциями-утилитами, и используете его в обеих реализациях. В этот новый класс (который по сути лишь контейнер методов) можно выгрузить общий код.
2. Вы заводите абстрактный суперкласс и помещаете общую функциональность туда. Это решение наверное удобнее в имплементации, но оно всё же определённо хуже, т. к. в наследовании участвует этот самый суперкласс, у которого вовсе нет отдельного смысла, он лишь деталь имплементации.

Comment: ага, я вот сделал интерфейс MyList и его имплементят оба класса. А на наследование не завязываюсь вообще. Там где методы одинаково реализуются, я просто их копирую. Получается все правильно делаю? И еще вопрос: в java есть только LinkedList, он двусвязный. То есть если пользователю нужен список (именно список, а не ArrayList) то он вынужден выбирать двусвязный. У него нет даже возможности выбрать односвязный. Как вы считаете, почему так сделано? Ведь если память нужно поэкономить, то односвязный лучше двусвязного.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: В принципе, вы делаете правильно. Но я бы не копировал методы, а вынес их куда-то в общее место. (Дописал ответ про это.)

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: По поводу односвязного списка, думаю, что это просто недореализованная функциональность. Он конечно нужен, но не так часто, так что его добавление в библиотеку отложили. С другой стороны, если что, его можно написать и вручную.

Comment: спасибо! А внутренний класс - это вы имеете внутренний для пакета? Потому что если я заведу в одном из классов внутренний класс - то я в другом не смогу вызывать его методы

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Угу, внутренний для пакета. Чтобы внешний мир его не видел.

Comment: А в каком случае односвязный список с указателем на начало и конец не является односвязным списком с указателем на начало?

Comment: @zRrr: Это вопрос уже о проектировании иерархии классов, это не ко мне. Мой ответ больше о технической стороне вопроса. // Например, если назвать тот, который с `Head`, _экономичным_, то здесь явно не будет наследования. Вопрос в том, какую семантику мы вкладываем.

Comment: @zRrr, Вот я как раз с точки зрения экономичности рассматривал их как два разных

Comment: @VladD, А можно еще третий вариант? Сделать все что надо в классе LinkedListWithHead, и потом воспользоваться композицией. То есть, в классе LinkedListWithHeadAndTail одним из полей будет LinkedListWithHead. Тогда, там где методы одинаковые, я просто смогу вызывать их из объекта LinkedListWithHead.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: По идее, можно и так, если вам удобно. Композиция по идее хорошее, правильное решение для повторного использования кода.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю стоит посмотреть как реализовано в **Java Collection Framework**. Т.к. по-сути он очень хорошо спроектирован и является отличным примером.

Если открыть исходники, то можно увидеть, что для списков используется абстрактный параметризированный класс `AbstractList<E>` который реализует интерфейс `List<E>`и является дочерним по отношению к `AbstractCollection<E>`

Т.е. в интерфейсе необходимо объявить ряд **общих** методов для списков, в абстрактном классе реализовать общую логику ну и в дочерних классах `LinkedListWithHead` и `LinkedListWithHeadAndTail` уже детали реализации.